# How can we mount volume on a container that's running without commit, stopping or pausing it?

Tags: docker, containers, volume, mount

I created a docker container that is already running a the bash.

```
$ docker run -ti ubuntu bash
```

In a new terminal I check for the running containers:

```
$ docker ps
```

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

354449b423e1        ubuntu              "bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       backstabbing_mestorf

Now I want to mount a drive that I have shared already on the running container without committing and creating a new image, neither pausing nor stopping it.So, I know

```
$ docker run ti -v /SrcDir:/Dest bash
```

The command above will create a new container but I don't want that. Is there a way where I will be able to mount and eject volumes from the host onto a running container?

Comment: There's a blog post about that here [Attach a volume to a container while it is running](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/).

Comment: From nsenter's readme - Caveats - nsenter still needs to run from the host; it cannot run inside a container (yet).
It still seems you need to start the container using docker-enter.

Comment: docker-enter starts a new container in the same context as your existing container. It's like `docker exec` before there was a docker exec. What you are asking to do is technically possible but inadvisable (outside of a learning exercise).